# Como saber el orden en que llegan las columnas de una consulta

Tags: android, mysql, webservice, android-volley

estoy realizando una app con Android Studio y estoy usando la libería Volley para consumir un servicio.

El web service me arroja estos datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en formato JSON, pero quisiera saber como hacer con un ciclo para poder obtener el nombre de las columnas,
} dado a que para obtener los datos hago esto.

```
JSONObject value = response.getJSONObject(0);
//si quiero obtener el apellido hago esto
apellito.setText = value.getString("apellido");
```

pero como podría hacer para evitar esto `value.getString("apellido")` y hacerlo mediante el orden de las columnas y así poder usarlo con un ciclo, algo así.

```
for(int i=0;i<tamaño;i++)
{
    valor.setText = value.getColumnIndex(i) 
    //getColummIndex lo acabo de inventar, es para que se entienda
}
```

y como lo dije "evitar esto"

```
nombre.setText = value.getString("nombre");
apellido.setText = value.getString("apellido);
.
.
.
ingreso.setText = String.valueOf(value.getDouble("ingresoanual"))
```

y así dependiendo de cuantas columnas lleguen.

Adjunto mi JSON.

> [{"id":"1","nombre":"Alan","apellidos":"Garcia","partido":"APRA","estudiouni":"SI","estudionouni":"SI","estudiotec":"NO","ingresoanual":"1000000"},{"id":"2","nombre":"Alejandro","apellidos":"Toledo","partido":"Peru
>   Posible","estudiouni":"SI","estudionouni":"SI","estudiotec":"NO","ingresoanual":"1350000"},{"id":"3","nombre":"Ollanta","apellidos":"Hulama","partido":"Partido
>   Nacionalista
>   Peruano","estudiouni":"SI","estudionouni":"NO","estudiotec":"NO","ingresoanual":"900000"},{"id":"4","nombre":"Alberto","apellidos":"Fujimori","partido":"Cambio
>   90","estudiouni":"NO","estudionouni":"SI","estudiotec":"NO","ingresoanual":"9999999"}]

Comment: ¿tienes problema con la IDE de Android: [tag:android-studio]? si no es asi no use esa etiqueta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        String value = json.getString(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

o pon el try cath afuera del while

Comment: funcionó correctamente junior, gracias. Una consulta más, en caso que quiera concatenar dos columnas, es que lo que estoy haciendo es mostrar los datos en una tabla, pero lo que hago primero es mostrar en una 1ra fila Los "Nombres y apellidos" y en la 2d fila los datos restantes (Pero aun así sigue conformando una fila todo junto). Como podría hacerlo.